# Tweaking the default animation for dark/light mode in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I made a very simple approach for dark/light theme switching. Inside a theme provider, I have:

```
 bool _isLightMode = true;
  get isLightMode => _isLightMode;
  set setLightMode(bool state) {
    _isLightMode = state;
    notifyListeners();
  }

ThemeData getTheme() {
    return ThemeData(
      colorScheme: isLightMode
          ? const ColorScheme.light().copyWith(
              primary: const Color.fromRGBO(0xD9, 0xAA, 0x55, 1),
            )
          : const ColorScheme.dark()
              .copyWith(primary: const Color.fromRGBO(0xD9, 0xC8, 0xA9, 1)),
      splashColor: Colors.transparent,
      highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
      fontFamily: "Roboto",
    );
  }
```

And an IconButton simply switches the theme:

```
// IconButton
// theme is an instance of the theme provider
callback: () {
            theme.setLightMode = !theme.isLightMode;
          },
icon: Icon(theme.isLightMode ? Icons.dark_mode : Icons.light_mode),
```

and finally in the root widget:

```
return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: theme.getTheme(),
      home: Builder(builder: (context) {
      ...
```

Everything works well. The only problem is that the theme transition from dark to light and vice versa, is very slow. Flutter is obviously using some kind of transition to do so, how can I tweak its parameters?

I know about the [animated_theme_switcher](https://pub.dev/packages/animated_theme_switcher) package. But I prefer not to use it since I don't want to use such capabilities. I simply want to change the default animation parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this:

1. removed the theme data from MaterialApp.
2. Wrapped each screen's scaffold with:

   ```
     return AnimatedTheme(
          data: theme.getTheme(),
          curve: Curves.easeInOut,
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 5),
          child: Scaffold(
                 ...
   ```

Now it's more controllable.